# Azure ML Studio Edit Metadata Not Working

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, ml-studio

Apologies if this proves to be an obvious answer, but I've been playing with this for a while, and suspect I'm misunderstanding something about ML Stuido.  I've been playing with the Matchbox Recommendations Sample (found [here](https://gallery.azure.ai/Experiment/Product-Recommendation-2)).  In order to see how the data manipulation worked, I removed the "Edit Metadata" step and tried to re-add it.  My understanding is that this step simply changes the label of the field from Id to User:

[image: Metadata]

However, after I remove and re-add it (and re-link it up):

[image: Relink]

The subsequent task (Select columns in dataset) is now in error, because it no longer recognised User:

[image: Select Columns]

Is this some quirk of ML studio (do I need to press a button or something to refresh it - I can't see anything obvious), or am I misunderstanding what should be happening here?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried the following steps and it works for me. 
You can't find 'User' in 'Select columns in dataset' because you need to run only 'Edit metadata' step first and then ML Studio will 'know' about new column name.

1. Link again.
2. Press 'Run' button.
3. Wait only until you will see a green mark on 'Edit metadata' (don't wait till the end of your experiment).
4. Press 'Stop' button.
5. Choose 'Select columns in dataset' -> 'Launch column selector' and choose 'User' from the list.